# How do you save an array in async storage in react native ?

Tags: asynchronous, react-native, local-storage

I am trying to create a save for later list, what type of storage is best for this async storage or some other method?

Is there an example of saving an array in this method?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Convert your array to a string using `JSON.stringify` on save and back to an array using `JSON.parse` on read:

```
var myArray = ['one','two','three'];

try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', JSON.stringify(myArray));
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}

try {
  const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
  if (myArray !== null) {
    // We have data!!
    console.log(JSON.parse(myArray));
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

Modified example from https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

Comment: what if array's length is 1 mil records?

Comment: @VityaSchel On android react native async storage size has been set to 6MB so I don't think it can accommodate that much data.